# Unexpected results when using java regex Matcher

Tags: java, regex

The regex pattern in my test program is:

```
"^#\\{\\S+\\}(:\\$\\{(\\d)\\})+$"
```

---

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class RegexPatternTest2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line1 = "#{aaa0}:${a22}:${10}";
        String line2 = "#{aaa0}:${0}:${1}";

        String line3 = "#{aaa0}:${a22}:${0}";

        check(line1);
        check(line2);
        check(line3);

    }
    public static void check(String line) {
        System.out.println("========================" + line);

        String keyPattern = "^#\\{\\S+\\}(:\\$\\{(\\d)\\})+$";

        Pattern r1 = Pattern.compile(keyPattern);
        Matcher m1 = r1.matcher(line);
        if(m1.matches()) {
            System.out.println("match line!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("error! can not match line: " + line);
        }
    }
}
```

I got the output below:

```
========================#{aaa0}:${a22}:${10}
error! can not match line: #{aaa0}:${a22}:${10}
========================#{aaa0}:${0}:${1}
match line!
========================#{aaa0}:${a22}:${0}
match line!
```

I expected the `Pattern` to match the sequence in the `String` variable `line2`, but the test result of `line3` make me confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `\S` will first swallow everything before giving back.

In your second example, the first part really matches `#{aaa0}:${0}`, and *not* `#{aaa0}` as you suspect.

It therefore stands to reason that the third line matches as well (with the first part matching `#{aaa0}:${a22}`)... You have to replace your `\S` with something more precise (maybe `[^}]`?).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match multiple digits, you need to add the + quantifier after your `\d`:

```
\\d+
```

Comment: I know that's a  common beginner's mistake (like expecting `\w` to match a whole word), but he really does want to match exactly one digit.  That's why his first sample input is supposed to fail.